# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly #2

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

The modification i made, before getting this error. I have Changed `byte[]` to `Stream` in all my classes.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.    
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---       

Server stack trace:     
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)


Exception rethrown at [0]:     
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
   at MyWCFServiceTest.MyWCFService.ICommonService.UploadDocument(UploadDocumentRequest request)    
   at MyWCFServiceTest.MyWCFService.MyServiceClient.MyWCFServiceTest.MyWCFService.ICommonService.UploadDocument(UploadDocumentRequest request) in C:\Users\KishoreJangid\Desktop\ChangeSAPTransactionStatus\MyWCFServiceTest - Copy\MyWCFServiceTest\Service References\MyWCFService\Reference.cs:line 2376    
   at MyWCFServiceTest.MyWCFService.MyServiceClient.UploadDocument(RequestHeader UploadDocumentReqHdr, Byte[]& UploadDocumentContent) in C:\Users\KishoreJangid\Desktop\ChangeSAPTransactionStatus\MyWCFServiceTest - Copy\MyWCFServiceTest\Service References\MyWCFService\Reference.cs:line 2383    
   at MyWCFService.Form1.DocumentUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\KishoreJangid\Desktop\ChangeSAPTransactionStatus\MyWCFServiceTest - Copy\MyWCFServiceTest\Form1.cs:line 88
```

Comment: Enable tracing for WCF in the *.config for the failing endpoint...you will probably get a much more detailed exception. The exception you posted is generic/useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lack of explanation given of what you're trying to achieve, have you updated all of your consumers to use the new classes?  I presume you've changed the data contracts and this broken consumers.

If not I would look at how much data you are transferring, please refer to this [blog post](http://kjellsj.blogspot.co.uk/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html)!  Seems likely this is the issue.

I had some problems with the same, it could be a configuration issue or if you are hosting in IIS, an issue there regarding permissions, please elaborate when you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an return from called method and using WCF service, then one possible cause behind this error could be your object serialization/de-serialization problem. If your service method returns something that is not serialize-able then your proxy channel makes this error.

To avoid this, just check-

1. The return type and make sure it is serializable. You may have to put [Serializable] attribute with your class.
2. Have `[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]`, it tells that the value will be present while serializing ( its says underline property is a non-nullable value type).
3. Make sure your enum values are matched with the values stored inside tables. This is the very critical situation because you don't expect it.